# Selected value using jQuery, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Does anybody know why I cannot specify the default value this way when it is pulling values from MySQL? I am ultimately trying to have it repopulate the dropdown lists with the appropriate $_REQUEST fields, so that editing can be easier.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#region").load('getRecords.php?start=regions');
    });   //jQuery initializations 
...............

<select 
    class    = "region"
    name     = "region"
    onchange = "value = this.value; 
               $('.country').load('getRecords.php?region='+value)
">

    <option>.....Reading database.....</option>
</select>

<script>$('.region').val('Africa');</script> 
...............
```

This is the kind of info that gets placed

```
<option value = "">Select One Region-------</option>

<option value="Africa">Africa</option>

<option value="Americas">Americas</option>

<option value="Asia">Asia</option>

<option value="Australasia">Australasia</option>

<option value="Europe">Europe</option>

<option value = "">------or a Sub-Region------</option>

<option value="Alps">Alps</option>

<option value="Amazon">Amazon</option>
//ETC>>>>
```

I can only get the jQuery .val method to work for very simple setups.

Comment: you should really be keeping your JS code separate from your HTML

Comment: I agree. But then I thought the sequence might have been the issue, so I put it right underneath. Hah.

Comment: You should look into the optgroup property http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: These cascading lists are basically my only option, there are around 4300 provinces, which is the lowest hierarchical level I am aiming for :)

Comment: @stefgosselin Alas, read http://w3fools.com/ why referencing to w3schools is not advisable.

Comment: @Alex It was not the best reference I sadly agree but good enough to get the point across.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are aiming for but maybe something like this will give you a nudge in the right direction (taken from the top of my head), probably has syntax errors.

```
$("select.region option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$("select.region option[value='Africa']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("region").selectedIndex=0;//put index of the element which you want as default
```

and give id="region" in select tag

Comment: This will only select the first `option`. The asker wants to set a default value for the `select`. In this case, it can be any `option` in the list, provided that `option` is defined.

Comment: Op has jquery goodness available, why the document.getElementById() calls when you have Jquery begging to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid `<option value="Africa">` first before you can make that value become the default. `<select>` tags do not have arbitrary `value` attributes.

Comment: The values are getting populated via MySQL. Is that not valid option? Along with a lot of other regions.

Comment: Where the data is ultimately stored is not the point. The problem is that your markup is wrong. You can get values from MySQL via. an AJAX response or whatever other means you like, but once you have them, you need to create an `<option>` tag for each, and then select one of those `<option>` tags to be the default.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, and I have no idea why you would think I would be pulling options without option tags.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend like below:

```
$('#region option[value="' + response_var[0].columnname + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```